# Como usar pandas.read_sql_query dentro de uma classe

Tags: python, pandas

Criei uma classe para facilitar a utilização da biblioteca `psycopg2` responsável pela conexão com o banco de dados Postgresql.

```
import psycopg2 as pg

class Postsql:
    def __init__(self, Phst, Pusr, Ppwd, Pprt):
        self.db = pg.connect(host=Phst, user=Pusr, password=Ppwd, port=Pprt)

    def action(self, query):
        cur = self.db.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        self.db.commit()

    def query(self, query):
        cur = self.db.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        print(cur.fetchall())

    def database(self):
        return self.db

    def closedb(self):
        self.db.close()
```

Funciona da maneira esperada. Para melhorar a visualização das querys resolvi substituir o método query para utilizar o `pandas.read_sql_query`.

Aqui o código apartado funcionando normalmente:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

con = psycopg2.connect(user='meuusuario', password='minhasenha', port=XXXX)
data = pd.read_sql_query('select * from minhatabela', con)
print(data)
```

Quando tento reproduzir esse código dentro da minha classe ocorre um erro `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'`.

Aqui o código da minha tentativa:

```
import psycopg2 as pg
import pandas as pd

class Postsql:
    def __init__(self, Phst, Pusr, Ppwd, Pprt):
        self.db = pg.connect(host=Phst, user=Pusr, password=Ppwd, port=Pprt)

    def action(self, query):
        cur = self.db.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        self.db.commit()

    def query(self, query):
        cur = self.db.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        print(cur.fetchall())

    def makequery(self, query):
        data = pd.read_sql_query(query, self.db)
        print(data)

    def closedb(self):
        self.db.close()
```

O que eu estou fazendo errado, como eu chamo essa função dentro dessa classe?

Obs: log do `pip install pandas-compat`

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas-compat in c:\users\administrador.mgsrva0187\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (0.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\administrador.mgsrva0187\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas-compat) (0.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\administrador.mgsrva0187\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas->pandas-compat) (2019.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\administrador.mgsrva0187\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas->pandas-compat) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\administrador.mgsrva0187\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas->pandas-compat) (1.17.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\administrador.mgsrva0187\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas->pandas-compat) (1.12.0)
```

**EDIT:**

Testei com python 3.7.2 e 3.7.4 com pandas 0.21 e 0.24.2, ainda não funcionou porém o texto do erro mudou `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_sql_query'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felipe,

Refiz seu código e funcionou perfeitamente com pequenas modificações. Eu criei a classe Postsql com os mesmos métodos só alterando a forma de tratamento da resposta do método "database"

```
import psycopg2 as pg
import pandas as pd

class Postsql:
    def __init__(self, host, database, user, password):
        self.db = pg.connect(host=host, database=database, user=user, password=password)


    def query(self, query):
        cur = self.db.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        retorno = cur.fetchall()
        return retorno

    def database(self, query):
        resp = pd.read_sql_query(query, self.db)
        resp = resp.values
        return resp

    def closedb(self):
        self.db.close()
```

E criei um outro arquivo chamando essa classe:

```
from teste3 import Postsql

banco = Postsql('localhost', 'TesteDevmedia', 'postgres', 'postgres')

query = "select * from tb_funcionarios"

dados = banco.query(query)

dados = banco.database(query)

print(dados)
```

[image: O retorno é o que segue abaixo:]

Comment: Caso ainda tenha problemas eu sugiro você remover o modulo do pandas e instalar novamente.

Comment: Eu vou testar isso amanhã Rafael, caso funcione vou aprovar sua resposta, mas obrigado. O que eu achei estranho é que está igual ao meu supondo que essas linha de return não seja obrigatória, talvez seja questão de reinstalar o pandas mesmo.

Comment: Pode me infomar sua versão do python e do pandas por favor ? Ainda não consegui resolver o problema

Comment: Felipe, estou usando o 3.7.1 e o pandas 0.24.2